# WebDav server on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, webdav, microsoft-office-2010

Question: Is there a way to set up a WebDAV server on windows 7 pro?

---

Info: My mom works for a non-profit psychology clinic that just got new computers. They have win7 pro and office 2010 on all their computers. They want to be able to share their calendars between their computers, yet the only way that it seems to do that is that it seems one can do such is to through an exchange server or WebDAV sever. (their upper ups don't really understand much about computers so they aren't willing to use any cloud based systems, which would solve all their problems) Now the local computer shop that sold them their systems is telling them they need to get a server to put exchange on, and they are wanting to charge them 3000$ that they really don't have.

What I'm convinced they could do is install a webDAV server on to one of their computers and they would be spared that pointless expenditure. but I can't find a windows installation of webDAV on the internet that wasn't a part of windows server. Does anyone know where I might be able to find a windows installation of webDAV server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know where I might be able to find a windows installation of webDAV server?

Yes:
http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/

BTW, I do not recommend using the default WebDAV client that comes with Windows.
The reason is explained here:
http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/tutorials/mapping_windows_drive.lsp

Comment: hmmm. do you happen to know if there is a free webDAV server? this works, but sadly they'd have to get a professional license. 200 < 3000, but still.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an online calendar? There are a number of them available, many of them free, and several that integrate with Outlook if that's the email client that's being used.

Comment: note my comment in the parens "their upper ups don't really understand much about computers so they aren't willing to use any cloud based systems, which would solve all their problems" I agree with you totally Joe, but thier boss is a loon and don't think that these options are safe. so nothing can be done across the internet, only lan.

Comment: I wouldn't call an online calendar a cloud based solution, but I get the dillema you're in.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a Windows Server somewhere on the LAN that has some spare bandwidth you could install Windows SharePoint Services 3 (aka SharePoint 2007) and use the calendar there.  It is hardly ideal but it would be a free calendar.  It just can't be the Domain controller as SharePoint doesnt work well on DCs.

I would not recommend SharePoint 2010 as the system requirements for that are substantial and are likely far beyond what a non-profit would have readily available.

Comment: they don't have a server, and I'm trying to avoid having to get one. because the server will cost stupid amounts of money they don't have. their system consists of 3 laps tops and 2 desktops. the local computer guy wants to charge them 3000$ for a server to sync a calendar between those? just ridiculous.